# How to get all the data from cache in java?

Tags: java, caching, jcs

Here, I am using the Java Caching System (JCS). I can put and get data in the cache. I need the whole data set for example like a key-value pair. Please guide me a way to retrieve it.

```
package net.practice.so;

import org.apache.jcs.JCS;
import org.apache.jcs.access.exception.CacheException;
import org.apache.jcs.engine.control.CompositeCacheManager;

import java.util.Properties;

public class JcsPractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CacheException {

        CompositeCacheManager ccm = CompositeCacheManager.getUnconfiguredInstance();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("jcs.default", "DC");
        ccm.configure(props);

        JCS cache = JCS.getInstance("numberCache");
        cache.put(1, "one");
        cache.put(2, "two");
        cache.put(3, "three");

        System.out.println(cache.get(2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please only show as much code as is needed to understand your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please be respectful with peoples time that are willing to help.

Comment: can u help me please?

Comment: Nominated for reopening, since @misbah thankfully extracted the actual question.

Comment: Why are you using a cache and not a simple HashMap?